# Computing the integral over $\Bbb R^3$ of a certain rational function

Tags: integration

I am trying to compute the following integral, or at least determine whether it converges:
$${\Large\iiint\limits_{\Bbb R^3}}\!\!\frac{
   \left( \frac{1}{1+x^2} \frac{1}{1+y^2} \frac{1}{1+z^2} \right)^2 
}{
   1-\frac{1}{144} \left( \frac{1}{1+x^2} +\frac{1}{1+y^2} +\frac{1}{1+z^2} \right)^2
}\,dV$$

I have tried in Wolfram without success.

Maybe somebody has an idea?

Thanks a lot for your help
G.OLDANI

Comment: \int_{0}^{\infty}?

Comment: The convergence of the integral is unproblematic, $\frac{1}{1+x^2} + \frac{1}{1+y^2} + \frac{1}{1+z^2} \leqslant 3$, hence the denominator is $\geqslant \frac{15}{16}$, and the numerator is $\leqslant \frac{1}{(1+x^2)(1+y^2)(1+z^2)}$, so the integral is $\leqslant \frac{16}{15}\pi^3$. Computing the exact value seems to be difficult, however.

Comment: Thanks Daniel,

I want to improve more the upper bound you gave do you have an advise how to approach this problem?

Regards
Gianfranco

Answer (score 0):

This is just an extended comment, not an answer, and doesn't necessarily seem to lead anywhere.
\begin{multline*}
{\Large\iiint\limits_{\Bbb R^3}}\!\!\frac{
   \left( \frac{1}{1+x^2} \frac{1}{1+y^2} \frac{1}{1+z^2} \right)^2 
}{
   1-\frac{1}{144} \left( \frac{1}{1+x^2} +\frac{1}{1+y^2} +\frac{1}{1+z^2} \right)^2
}\,dV \\
={\Large\iiint\limits_{\Bbb R^3}}\!\!\frac{
   \left( \frac{1}{1+x^2} \frac{1}{1+y^2} \frac{1}{1+z^2} \right)^2 
}{
   1-\frac{1}{144} \left( \frac{(1+y^2)(1+z^2)+(1+x^2)(1+z^2)+(1+x^2)(1+y^2)}{(1+x^2)(1+y^2)(1+z^2)} \right)^2
}\,dV\\
=\iiint\limits_{\Bbb R^3}\!\!\tfrac{1}{((1+x^2)(1+y^2)(1+z^2))^2-\frac1{144}((1+y^2)(1+z^2)+(1+x^2)(1+z^2)+(1+x^2)(1+y^2))^2}\,dV
\end{multline*}
and then that has a denominator of the form $a^2-b^2$, which factors nicely